# How to split and merge javascript object with respect to index of array attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

How to split and merge javascript object with respect to index of array attribute.

I have fields like that.

```js
var myFields = {
  Country: "USA",
  State: "DC",
  Cataogry: ["Value1", "Value2"],
  Level: ["Level1", "Level2"]
};
```

I want to derive two from here like this. Output : -

```js
var fields = [
  { Country: "USA", State: "DC", Cataogry: "Value1", Level: "Level1" },
  { Country: "USA", State: "DC", Cataogry: "Value2", Level: "Level2" }
];
```

So When I am using my code I am getting 4 arrays instead of two. Can anybody help me with how to merge with respect to the index.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
var myObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  myObj[fields[i].key] = fields[i].Value;
}

var myObjList = [];
var listFlag = false;
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key) {
  if (Array.isArray(myObj[key])) {
    listFlag = true;
    myObj[key].forEach(function(el) {
      var objCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj));
      objCopy[key] = el;
      myObjList.push(objCopy);
    });
  }
});

if (!listFlag) {
  myObjList.push(myObj);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a dynamic approach and iterate all entries and have a look to `value`.

If `value` is an array, map the values along with the object at the same index or take the first object as pattern.

If `value` is no array, map the accumulator and add the actual key/value pair to all objects.

```js
var object = { Country: "USA", State: "DC", Category: ["Value1", "Value2"], Level: ["Level1", "Level2"] },
    result = Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce(
            (r, [key, value]) => Array.isArray(value)
                ? value.map((v, i) => ({ ...(r[i] || r[0]), [key]: v }))
                : r.map(o => ({ ...o, [key]: value })),
            [{}]
        );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `map` method.

```js
var myFields = {
    "Country" : "USA",
    "State" : "DC",
    "Cataogry" : ["Value1","Value2"],
    "Level" : ["Level1","Level2"]
}

var fields = myFields.Cataogry.map((item, index) => ({
  Country : myFields.Country,
  State : myFields.State,
  Cataogry: myFields.Cataogry[index],
  Level : myFields.Level[index]
} ));

console.log(fields);
```

Comment: This solution is correct but I want to be generic one. I don't wantto use all the attributes. The way I have tried in my example.

Comment: Yes, but what is `fields` in your question ? Because you specified that `fields` is the `output`.

Comment: fields is a veriable where I am storing the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` it. Here is my try. I'm assuming category and level are of the same length.

```js
var myFields = {
  Country: "USA",
  State: "DC",
  Cataogry: ["Value1", "Value2"],
  Level: ["Level1", "Level2"]
};

var result = myFields.Cataogry.map((Cataogry, i) => ({
  ...myFields,
  Cataogry,
  Level: myFields["Level"][i]
}));

console.log(result);
```